# How to add removed element to the end of the list?

Tags: python

I need to remove the first element from a list and add it to the end of the list.

```
def first():
    list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
    del list1[0]
    print(list1)

first()
```

I know how to delete or pop an element, but don't know how to add this removed element back to the end of the list.

Comment: You add the popped element to the end of a list the way you add _any_ element to the lis. Since you already know how to _pop_ the element, what is the trouble appending it to the end of the list?

Answer (score 4):

Use `pop` and `append`:

```py
>>> list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> list1.append(list1.pop(0))
>>> list1
['b', 'c', 'a']
```

Or use slicing to build a new list (which you can assign back to `list1` if you like, or mutate the original via slice assignment):

```
>>> list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> list1[1:] + list1[:1]
['b', 'c', 'a']
```